# Distribution of mean of a random vector

Tags: probability, statistics

If we have a n by 1 random vector y which follows a normal distribution, y~Normal(0,V) where V is the variance-covariance matrix (generally isn't Iσ²). How do we derive the distribution of y_bar?

So E(y_bar) is 0, but how do I derive variance of y_bar? Is it same as a univariate case, so just V/n (I suspect not but I don't know how to proceed...)?

Comment: Are you looking for a single number or a matrix as the answer?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a single number... Michael's answer seems about right

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the $1\times n$ vector (1,1,...,1).
$\overline{y}=xy/n$, where $xy$ is a matrix product, and a $1\times1$ matrix.
$$E(\overline{y}^2)=E\left((xy/n)(y^Tx^T/n)\right)\\=E(xyy^Tx^T/n^2)=xE(yy^T)x^T/n^2=xVx^T/n^2$$